# Determining if a SIMM is EDO

Tags: memory, specifications

I’ve used some simple methods to determine the parity and speed, and calculate the size of several SIMM sticks, but now I need to figure out if they are EDO.

Does anyone know of a way to determine whether a SIMM is EDO or not?

Comment: ???​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Bad joke about somebody seeing "SIMM" and assuming you mean "SIM card" because they're not old school enough to have any idea what a SIMM is.

Comment: Ah okay. I even tried Googling *SIMM* to see if there was a phone-related thing, but didn’t think of SIM. `>.<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually they're labeled (since there were problems with mixing EDO and the older FPM stuff even though a lot of components were compatible with either/or), but I'm guessing these may be old enough that labels have gone missing.  If you have the part numbers I'd recommend actually looking them up - I'm not aware of any way to query for this in software.  You might try a tool like [AIDA64 (formerly Everest)](http://www.aida64.com/) to query the exact model numbers and go from there.  (EDIT: But again, if they're old enough, you may not even be able to get that.)

Comment: (Windows software is out of the questions.) I already tried Googling, but one (`HY85117800BJ-60 9820` on the chips, `B7682A` on the PCB) doesn’t have any info on whether it is EDO or FPM (or even the size for that matter; there’s a hand-made sticker that says 16MB). The other one only has ‘Panasonic’ stamped on the heat-spreader along with a sticker marked`EUXSX08TV07A 4903209G` and `LPB0140` on the back of the PCB, which come up with **nothing at all**. Prying up the heat-spreader shows the chips are *completely unmarked*!

Comment: There may be similar software for a DOS or UNIX environment (I'm assuming that even if you have a machine these run in it's fairly old) but I don't know what.  My point is that's the sort of thing you'd need.  You may be out of luck unless somebody comes along and knows some magic bit of code you can get to return a flag, sorry. :/

Comment: But it is possible to get that info programmatically? If so, then I’ll give HWiNFO a shot.

Comment: I'm not sure, hence heavy use of 'might'.  I don't see how it'll hurt to try though!  My hunch is that probably you can't. :/

Answer (score 3):

As Shinrai suggested a few years ago, the easiest way is to look on the memory sticks themselves and see if they are marked. If it says "EDO" somewhere, then you know for sure it's EDO. Similarly, if it says "FPM" somewhere, then you know it is *not* EDO. If it says neither of those two things, or the label has gone missing, then you know nothing and have to try something else.

Each individual memory chip has a part number silk-screened onto it. This has the advantage of never rubbing or falling off, but the distinct disadvantages of being vendor-specific, cryptic, and difficult to interpret. Fortunately, if all you want to know is whether the SIMM is FPM or EDO, there is a surprisingly accurate heuristic: look specifically at the *numeric* portion of the part number (ignoring any letters that may be appended to the end). If this numeric portion of the part number ends in 0, then you have FPM memory. If it ends in a non-zero number (odd numbers like 3, 5, 7, and 9 are probably most common, but I've also seen 4 and 8), then you can be pretty confident that you have EDO memory.

For example, I have here a 16 MB SIMM. Its individual memory chips are manufactured by Motorola, and they have the part number `M5M417400AJ`. Following the above heuristic, we isolate the numeric portion of that part number: `417400`. Since this number ends in 0, we can be pretty confident that it is FPM, *not* EDO. And indeed, we would be correct. (This is actually a rather common part number for 4M×4 memory chips, regardless of vendor—8 of these would give you a 16 MB SIMM).

Another example: a Kingston 8 MB module contains memory chips with the part number `MT4C4007JDJ`. The numeric portion is `4007`, which ends with a 7, suggesting it is an EDO part. Indeed, that turns out to be precisely correct.

Finally, a third IBM OEMed SIMM I have here has Oki memory chips with the part number `M5117405A-60SJ`. Now you have to be a bit careful. The portion *after* the dash actually gives the timing, in nanoseconds. So this is a 60 ns part. The timing coming after a dash is also a very common rule across vendors, but some omit the dash, so you do need to watch out for this. The first two examples didn't have the timing in the part number (it was printed elsewhere on the memory chip), but for those that do, it will always be the *last* number of the part number, in either nanoseconds or tens of nanoseconds. To assess FPM vs. EDO, you need to look at the numeric portion of the part number that is *not* the timing. In this case, that would be `5117405`. Since this value ends in 5, it suggests that this is an EDO SIMM, and indeed it is a 16 MB EDO module.

[image]

In general, it doesn't matter *which* of the memory chips you look at on the module—they will all have the same part number (as you can see in the image above). The only exception is when you have a *parity* module. You can tell that a module is parity because it will have an odd number of chips (the extra one stores the parity information). So normally, a SIMM will have 2, 4, or 8 DRAM chips on a side. That's a non-parity module, and all the chips will be identical. A parity module will have something like 3, 5, or 9 DRAM chips, and you want to ignore the part number on the odd-man-out.

This method used to work fantastically well for me when I was digging through parts bins and didn't have a computer handy (this was long before smart phones existed; now I unfortunately can't find anywhere that has vintage parts lying around!).

If you are nearby a computer, you can also plug the module's part number into your favorite search engine. This will pull up a large number of results, but you should be able to scan through them quickly, looking for a data sheet. Once you find the data sheet, in 90% of cases, it will indicate very clearly whether the part is designed for EDO or not. For example, [this is the first hit for the second part number given above](http://www.questcomp.com/InventoryItems.aspx?pn=MT4C4007JDJ-6)—note that it confirms our heuristic-based approach.

The absolute *best* way, though, is to insert the SIMM into a motherboard. This obviously requires that you have suitable hardware, but presumably you do if you care about memory modules of this vintage! (If you don't, leave a comment and you can mail them my way.)

One option is a 486-era board that you know does *not* support EDO memory. You can install the module(s) here, and if the board successfully POSTs (powers on), then you know that the module is *not* EDO. If it beeps and fails POST, then the module is either EDO or it is defective. The advantage of the 486 board is that they only have a 32-bit data path, meaning that SIMMs do not need to be installed in pairs, allowing you to test individual SIMMs.

If you have a pair of SIMMs, an even better option is a Pentium-era board that supports either type of memory. (The Pentium had a 64-bit data path, so 32-bit SIMMs had to be installed in pairs.) These boards will inevitably have some indication of the type of memory that is installed, either hidden in the CMOS Setup or displayed in a big box on the initial power-on screen. It will either explicitly say whether the bank contains FPM or EDO RAM, or it will indicate Yes/No for EDO in that bank. Either way, this provides the definitive proof. I've done this and scrawled labels on all of my modules using a thin marker.